# UTC issue on formatting date

Tags: javascript, typescript, utc, date-fns

[image]I have this react typescript/js code:

```
   fromDate: fromDate.toISOString().split('T')[0], // formatted to 2000-01-01
```

but it's not working properly.  It changes fromDate to the next day when I run it late at night.  So I tried on 6/30/2022 at 11pm and it changed it to 7/1/2022.

My attempted fix is to use date-fns format function:

```
fromDate: format(Date.parse(fromDate.toLocaleString()), 'yyyy-MM-dd'),// formatted to 2000-01-01
```

My question is will this resolve the utc issue?
Maybe I should rather change the datepicker that gets the fromDate to ignore times?

How can I test it without trying it at 11pm?

This image attached is how it looked in the console when I console logged the problem:
The top line is `console.log(fromDate)`. The bottom line is `console.log(fromDate.toISOString().split('T')[0])`

Comment: `toISOString` prints a UTC Timestamp. So if you localTime is for instance `2022-07-27T23:00:00` but you are in a timezone that is 4 hours behind of UTC the respective UTC time is `2022-07-28T03:00:00` and that's what you are seeing ...

Comment: thanks, so you're saying my fix will work.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm saying. Especially, as I never used the `date-fns` library so I can't tell how it works. I just explained what happened. To fix your issue, you should clarify what you really want and what `fromDate` is supposed to be.

Comment: fromDate needs to be the date selected on the datepicker at 12am

Comment: But you are assigning `string`s to `fromDate` in both of your examples?

Comment: yes, but I don't think that's the issue.  I think the real issue is to .toISOstring changes the time.  as you see fromDate knows the proper time before it gets manipulated.

Comment: No it doesn't *change time*. It displays the same timestamp as UTC (because that's how it's defined). Handling timestamps can be very tricky. So you need to exactly know what you want and what you are doing. Otherwise you will get into a mess, without an easy way out. Believe me, I've been there. If you just want the current date in your local timezone as a string, your approach with `format` probably will do the trick. But depending on what you do with this timestamp later on, this might not be the correct approach.

Comment: I don't do anything else with fromDate after this.  I just send it in as query params and filter based on it in my api

Comment: OK, yes, then your approach with `format` should do the trick ... And you can easily test it with creating a `new Date(2022, 05, 30, 23, 0, 0, 0)` and then applying your conversion to it. This will create a timestamp with 11pm localtime, and as you are in a UTC-4 timezone this is 3am the next day in UTC ...

Comment: lol.  I was able to easily test:  const test = new Date('Thu june 30 2022 23:03:00 GMT-0400');
console.log(test.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
console.log(format(Date.parse(test.toLocaleString()), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

testing was easy!

```
const test = new Date('Thu june 30 2022 23:03:00 GMT-0400');
console.log(test.toISOString().split('T')[0]);
console.log(format(Date.parse(test.toLocaleString()), 'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

1st console.log shows problem
2nd console.log shows fixed problem.

Answer (score 1):

Format will not solve your UTC issue, you need to pass a timezone to `toLocaleString` yourself.

Rather than parsing the date yourself, you could also pass arguments to `toLocaleString` in order to choose a time zone and a format.

For instance:

```
const event = new Date();
let options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric',timeZone: 'EST' };
console.log(event.toLocaleString('en-US', options));
```

You can even pass an option for `weekday: 'long'` to tell toLocaleString to print out the actual name of a weekday.

As @derpirscher pointed out in the comments, since you are looking for `yyyy-MM-dd` formatting, the best approach will likely be to pass a timezone yourself and then parse the date as you have been doing:

```
format(Date.parse(fromDate.toLocaleString('en-US')), 'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

See [these docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)

Comment: Not sure if there's a way to test it without trying late at night, but if you specify a time zone yourself I don't see why it would fail.

Comment: Seems like OP doesn't want a localeString but the date in ISO format, ie `yyyy-MM-dd`. Furthermore, relying on the output format `toLocaleString` may be dangerous, as this may be implementation depended (altough I doubt there will any differences in various runtimes for the date of `en-US`)

Comment: True. It's definitely possible for OP to only pass the timezone and continue to parse that date by themself. Ex: `format(Date.parse(fromDate.toLocaleString('en-US')), 'yyyy-MM-dd')`. I just personally think it's probably easier to let the function do the work of formatting for you, but you're right, if there's a reason that `yyyy-MM-dd` formatting is needed, this approach is necessary.